# Soot Coming Out Of My Bathroom Electrical Outlet - What should I do?

Tags: electrical

I rent an apartment. There is a trail of soot coming out of my bathroom electrical outlet that runs from the outlet, upwards toward the ceiling. When I contacted the Manager, he has an "electrician" come and check it and all they do is replace the cover plate. I assume that the wiring is not code compliant as the building was built in 1958. I also assume that there would be no soot coming out of the outlet unless there is heat generating inside the outlet and could be fire hazard.

What should I do?

Comment: I added a question that I think you're asking, so your post can fit on this site. If you really wanted to know something else, please edit your question to ask the question you wanted.

Comment: Also, the country your apartment is in is important. Please edit that in. Some jurisdictions don't allow you to alter wiring in a rental property.

Comment: Is it soot from something burning?  If a long time, it might be dust/dirt coming from inside the wall, maybe a vent(chimney?) is leaking.  Is there any burning smell?

Comment: An [edit] to include a picture of the cover plate, at least, would help us understand what you're seeing. Usually, soot (from something burning) will wipe off at first, then, after a while it will solidify to the point where it won't wipe off. Will any of this wipe off? Also, have you contacted the landlord a 2nd time? Keep pestering him, reminding him that it's _his_ property that will burn down if it's not fixed right and he'll lose a lot more money than the cost of a licensed electrician coming to make a fix...

Answer (score 2):

Soot doesn't come out of an outlet under normal conditions. Soot means fire has been burning, and fire behind an outlet cover is a really bad thing. Merely replacing the outlet cover is hardly enough, if that is all that was done.

If you were not watching the work, it is possible that the electrician did actually fix a problem, likely tightening apparently still usable wiring connections that allowed the outlet to be used safely. Then again, maybe all they did was just replace the plate.

In many jurisdictions, only a licensed electrician can work on electrical installations in a rental property. You may have to study the legal situation in your jurisdiction to tell if you are under such a restriction.

If you are, you may have to convince the landlord to investigate the situation further, or check with your local authority what you are legally allowed to do to have the outlet rechecked by an electrician that the local authority recognizes.

If you are not under such a restriction, and you determine that you are legally allowed to do so, you (if you have the DIY electricity skills) or an electrician (if you don't have the DIY electricity skills) can turn off power to the outlet, unscrew the outlet out of the wall, and either repair what has gone wrong or take pictures and ask a new question about how to fix the problem seen in the pictures.

Comment: I believe it is more soot like, than actual soot as we understand soot.  I think OP has had electrician come around more than once and it seems to keep repeating.